# Break outside of loop when in loop?

Tags: python

My script returns an error saying `break` is outside of a loop when the `break` is inside an if statement.  Why? How do I fix this? Writing a script out of a book,

```
if hook_address:
    hooks.add(dbg,hook_address,2,ssl_sniff,None)
    print "[*] nspr4.PR_Write hooked at: 0x%o8x" %hook_address
    break
else:
    print "[!] Error: Couldn't resolve hook address!"
    sys.exit(-1)
```

> c:\0xic-zex\Python>sniffer.py   File "C:\0xic-zex\Python\sniffer.py",
>   line 32
>       break SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop

Whats wrong? My `break` is in the `if` loop.

Comment: `if` is not a loop. You don't need to break out of it in your given code. It will no way execute `else` once entering the `if`.

Answer (score 5):

`if` statements aren't loops.  You don't need to `break` out of them.

You would use `break` to leave a `for` or `while` loop early.

Comment: The book uses python 2.5, that might be why syntax is very off ( im coding in 2.7) , it should work regardless if i remove the break, right?

Comment: That hasn't changed between Python versions.  Are you sure this if statement isn't supposed to be in a loop that you're not showing us?  If not, you need a new book :)